# Running two versions of Python in one script. Possible?

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

I have a pure Python 3.7.3 and another Python 3.7.0 that comes with QGIS software bundle.

I set default Python as 3.7.0 and need to get some functions and modules working in 3.7.3.

I could set my default environment to a 3.7.3 but in this case I can not get an access to `qgis.core` lib. 
In 3.7.0 I need to perform `from PyQt5 import QtWidgets` but here it throws and error of missing dll. Re-installing `pyqt5` will harm `qgis` and totally delete it.

So I see that I need to run scripts from 3.7.0 with Qt functions that work in pure 3.7.3. But how can I put in my script. 
I tried to test `virtualenv` but looks like it doesn't want to set a temporary environment.

Comment: Can't you run both of it in 3.7.3?

Comment: Install QGIS in python3.7.3

Comment: You can run two interpreters and do IPC

Comment: It's not possible to install qgis on 3.7.3. It's python comes with qgis only

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you should deal with these issues and avoid using 2 different Python environments. But you could achieve this with *pyenv*.

Let's say that 3.7.0 is your system Python version. First, install *pyenv* and a *3.7.3* environment:

```
$ pyenv update
$ pyenv install 3.7.3
$ pyenv shell 3.7.3
```

Then, install *PyQt5* and the other requirements with *pip*.

Eventually, you will be able to switch to a every installed versions, manually or within your script.

*pyenv* also supports virtual environments.

Comment: pyenv is not available on Windows

Answer (score 0):

Made it.

In 3.7.0 script I add

```
import sys 
qt_bundle =['~long_path_to_appdata\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib\\site-packages\\'] # list in case I need to add more modules
sys.path+= qt_bundle
```

after that this statement

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
```

does not throw any error